# React route not found

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a nested structure where i host the react build as follows `level1/level2/level3`. When i hit the static hosted build using `serve` with `localhost:3000/level1/level2/level3` it redirects correctly to `localhost:3000/level1/level2/level3/title/cat/id`. But when i try to hit 
`localhost:3000/level1/level2/level3/title1/cat1/id1` directly it just returns `Not found`.

I have the browser router code as follows

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
             <Route path="/level1/level2/level3/:pageTitle/:category/:id" render={AppBody}/>
             <Redirect from="/level1/level2/level3/" to="/level1/level2/level3/title/cat/id"/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Why does default redirect work but not when we try to hit the url directly?What's the correct way to fix this?

Comment: what about adding `exact` prop to your route?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me, so I think there is some other aspect of your code that is causing a problem.
Here's a code sandbox with a simple index.js that includes your router code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vmyzkj1lvy

You can use this URL to see the results for the particular URL you mentioned:
https://vmyzkj1lvy.codesandbox.io/level1/level2/level3/title1/cat1/id1

Answer (score 0):

The problem could not be actually the react router but instead your server. So first check that your server is actually returning a response when visiting `/level1/level2/level3/title1/cat1/id1`.

Your react router is actually changing the url in the browser when it hits `<Redirect from="/level1/level2/level3/" to="/level1/level2/level3/title/cat/id"/>` **without** sending a request to the server.

You can use this python [gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisbolin/2e90bc492270802d00a6) as a server for static serving for your react app that I believe would solve your problem ;)